# Linux kernel can't mount /dev file system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm building a custom linux image, using a non-manipulated Linux kernel 2.6.32.65.

the kernel boots just fine until it reaches this:

```
EXT2-fs warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 3:1.
Freeing unused kernel memory: 304k freed
init: Unable to mount /dev filesystem: No such device
init: ureadahead main process (983) terminated with status 5
init: console-setup main process (1052) terminated with status 1
```

I tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116887/self-built-kernel-failed-to-mount-dev-no-such-device) although the error is not exactly the same, but no luck. I tried multiple "reference" `.config` files. I have been googling for a bit but I can't find anything with the same problem.

I'm running this custom image on *gem5* simulator, with file system from *ubuntu-core* and a clean kernel. earlier in the output the kernel shows this:

```
hda: max request size: 128KiB
hda: 16514064 sectors (8455 MB), CHS=16383/16/63
 hda: hda1
```

So the kernel is able to see partitions just fine. I don't think this is caused by something in the file system. maybe initrd? or the kernel itself? how can I fix it?

Comment: 1.) The problem is not in devfs, it seems issue is console setup. 2.) This is init issue not a linux kernel issue. 3.) Try to pass /bin/sh instead of init to kernel cmd line.

Comment: Ok that worked, post it as an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) The problem is not in devfs, it seems issue is console setup. 2.) This is init issue not a linux kernel issue. 3.) Try to pass /bin/sh instead of init to kernel cmd line

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with custom built embedded Linux.
Check you have enabled devfs in kernel .config

```
# core filesystems
CONFIG_PROC_FS=y
CONFIG_SYSFS=y
## devfs
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y
```